Disks close the axes do not appear
I have a table with many pairs of coordinates (many points) and I want to put disks on these points.
The color and the axes of the disks will depend on their position.
I used the following code but I see that the two disks with their centers on the axes - or very close to them - do not appear.
In the example below only the disk centered at (.6, .5) appears.
Any help?
tr = Transpose[{{.0, .5}, {.5, .0}, {.6, .5}}];

Graphics[{  
MapThread[{RGBColor[ 1  , .5 , .5  Abs[#2] ], 
 Disk[{#1, #2}, {  Abs[#1]   , Abs[#2]    }]} &, 
 tr]}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]               


Two of your disks look like this ‘ ,Disk[{0.,0.5},{0.,0.5}]’ ; so one semi-axis is zero.

My fault, thank a lot!
